# Create a BEFORE trigger in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I tried to create a BEFORE trigger in SQLite to log any updates to the values of the population attribute of the Country table.

First I created a table country_log using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE country_log (
    CountryCode    TXT,
    old_population INT,
    new_population INT,
    change_date    TXT
);
```

After I successfully created the table, I tried to use the following code to create a BEFORE trigger and to update a value in the Country table to avoid the "cannot commit - no transaction is active" error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_country_log

BEFORE UPDATE OF population ON country

BEGIN
INSERT INTO country_log VALUES
(NEW.code, OLD.population, NEW.population, datetime('now'));
END;

UPDATE country
SET population = 24433300
WHERE code = 'AUS';
```

The `CREATE TRIGGER`query was run successfully. However, after the query was run, there was still no entry in the country_log table and I still could not find any trigger displayed alongside the Country table. Why was this so?